# Highchart polar with additional pie series below

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to update our old chart rendering engine to Highcharts.

How can i draw a chart like this with Highcharts?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNdBM.png)

I think maybe there is some way to combine the polar chart and pie chart but still not find out how to do it.

Comment: Look at this as an example to start from: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-wind-rose

Comment: check my code here, the pie always on the top...
http://jsfiddle.net/z3Lr2z54/
And i cannot set the 'height' for the pie, not sure i am on the right track.

Comment: Set `zIndex` for the pie series as well to have it below. See http://jsfiddle.net/z3Lr2z54/1/

Comment: Thanks ewolden! this might help to solve the problem but d_paul have a better solution than ours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about instead of combining polar and pie charts, use only polar chart? I prepared an example for you where I am using four series. The first one has disabled `grouping` and `enableMouseTracking` and it is treated as a background. I also modified `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` to be able to display series exactly as in the provided image. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.grouping
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointPadding
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.groupPadding
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6hjefrcu/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's extracly what i need, master d_paul :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are adding the pie chart after the polar chart and the pie got on top of polar so you have 2 solutions

1.- add the pie chart before the polar chart
2.- play with zIndex; set zIndex of polar to 1 and zIndex of pie chart to 0 or in your code just set pie chart zIndex to -1

```
chartRender.addSeries({
  name: 'score-template',
  type: 'pie',
  slice: false,
  pointPlacement: 'between',
  data: [
      50, 80, 30
  ],
  zIndex: -1
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z3Lr2z54/2/